# how to use function call in db 2 load utility control file

Tags: sql, db2

i want to have a sample db2 control file that is inserting default value to a column such as..

```
LOAD
FROM "data.txt"
OF DEL
MODIFIED BY COLDEL|
TIMESTAMPFORMAT="YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"
MESSAGES "msg.txt"
INSERT INTO FILE_PROCESS_SUMMARY
(
***ID "101"***,
FIELD1,
FIELD2,
FIELD3,
.
.
.
.,
FIELDN
)
```

i want to fill the id field either with sequence, own value as "101" or would like to call a function whose return value i will be assigning.

kindly help me out how i can achieve my requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference functions in the `LOAD` command. What you can do is define your `ID` column as identity (`... ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 101)...`).

More info in the manual: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0004591.html?lang=en